# Isomorphism between tensor product of exterior power spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Suppose that $V_1, V_2, V_3$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimensions $d_1, d_2, d_3$, respectively. Suppose that $V_1, V_2, V_3$ are equipped with inner products, so that their duals are identified with themselves. The following spaces are of dimension $\binom{d_1 + d_2 + d_3}{d_1,d_2,d_3}$ over $\mathbb{C}$:
$$W_{1,2,3} = \wedge^{d_1}\left(V_1 \oplus V_2\right) \otimes \wedge^{d_1 + d_2} \left( V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_3 \right), \\ W_{3,2,1} = \wedge^{d_3}\left(V_3 \oplus V_2\right) \otimes \wedge^{d_3 + d_2} \left( V_3 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_1 \right).$$
I was wondering if there is a known setup where a canonical isomorphism between these two spaces exists.

For example, suppose that $V_1 = V_3$, then the spaces are naturally identified.

Another example is when $V_2=0$, in which case $\wedge^{d_1}\left( V_1 \right)$ and $\wedge^{d_3}\left( V_3 \right)$ are one dimensional vector spaces, both with a distinguished element (because $V_1$ and $V_3$ are equipped with inner products), and $\wedge^{d_1}\left( V_1 \oplus V_3 \right)$ is isomorphic to $\wedge^{d_3}\left( V_1 \oplus V_3 \right)$.

Are there any other known cases where the spaces can be naturally identified, given some assumptions on $V_1, V_2, V_3$?